# aws-sdk v2 to v3 migration question - IniLoader

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am doing an 'aws-sdk' v2 > v3 migration and I'm trying to find the v3 equivalent of the following v2 code:

```
const profiles = Object.keys((new AWS.IniLoader()).loadFrom({});
```

The closest thing I can find is this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-smithy-shared-ini-file-loader/

But this seems somewhat different. Is this what I'm looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the closest thing. Note that, as a general rule, there's no guarantee that a given utility function in SDK v2 will also be available in v3.